# Sefer about the writing of Neviim and Megillos

Tags: jewish-books, navi-prophets, writing-printing, safrus

What sefer discusses the details pertaining to the writing of Nevi'im and Megillos (i.e., how the paragraphs are broken up, where there are "special letters", etc.)?

Comment: Only Megillot and not the rest of Ketuvim?

Comment: Can you specify what you are looking for that isn't found in http://www.korenpub.com/EN/categories/tanakh

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't have access to the Koren edition right now. In any case, I was looking for something that discusses the details, not just a list of פתוחות וסתומות.

Comment: Sorry to press, but what else is there besides lists? I'm not sure what you mean by details.

Comment: @DoubleAA Let's say I was a sofer, and I want to sit down and write myself a set of Na"ch scrolls. I wouldn't feel comfortable just following any particular edition of Na"ch (even a very accurate one), as there are many important particulars which can't be conveyed in that format. For example, Rambam gives specific directions for the writing of Az Yashir -- it has to be 30 lines, and the phrases need to be staggered in a certain way. Looking in the Koren might give me the general idea, but I wouldn't really understand what's required.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Also, in some cases there are ambiguities or disagreements or alternate traditions, and I would want to be educated about these rather than relying on the decision of the editor of the Koren.

Comment: You might be able to use the book reviewed [here](http://torahmusings.com/2012/08/book-review-inside-stam-a-complete-buyers-guide/). I don't know all its contents, but you might want to look in it

Answer (score 3):

*Minchas Shay* is a commentary on *Tanach* that focuses on the correct reading (both *k'siv* and *k'ri*), including such things as paragraph breaks. (I don't know for certain that he comments on every *sefer* or which, but I know he does on many.) He does leave some questions open, mentioning both sides, and even where he takes a side I don't know whether *sof'rim* follow his decisions — but he is considered an authoritative source.

Answer (score 0):

Meschet sofrim which is part of the mesechot katanot in bavli.  It was written during the timesvof the geonim.

Comment: Is an English translation of that available on the Internet?

Comment: Does masechet sofrim list all the petuchot and setumot in Nach?

Comment: It is not comprehensive. As a random example, I didn't see a word about how Megillas Eichah is to be written.